# Storing string versions of database status values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 3 site and I need to convert some integer values from the database that represent statuses with user readable strings, for example:

```
...
<td>
@item.Status
</td>
...
```

I've written an HTML Helper to do the conversion:

```
    public static string MessageType(this HtmlHelper helper, int type)
    {
        string messageType = "Unknown";
        switch((Types.MessageTypes)type)
        {
            case Types.MessageTypes.Join:
                messageType = "Join App";
                break;
            case Types.MessageTypes.New:
                messageType = "New App";
                break;
        }

        return messageType;
    }
```

And I'm storing the types as an enumeration in the Types class.

My question is whether there is a cleaner way to do this?  I don't like these magic strings in my code and it creates numerous dependencies in different parts of the code.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usual decorate the enums with the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) like this.

```
    enum MessageTypes
    {
       [Display(Name = "Join App")]   
       Join,
       [Display(Name = "New App")]     
       New
    }
```

Then I use a helper to extract them:

```
    public static string EnumDisplay(this HtmlHelper helper, Enum model)
    {
        var enumType = model.GetType();
        var modelValue = Convert.ToInt64(model);

        var matches = from field in enumType.GetMembers()
                      where field.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field && Enum.IsDefined(enumType, field.Name)
                      let value = Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(enumType, field.Name, false))
                      where modelValue == value
                      let attribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DisplayAttribute), false).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
                      select attribute == null 
                          ? field.Name 
                          : attribute.Name;

        return matches.FirstOrDefault() ?? "Unknown";
    }
```

Then you can do

```
  @Html.EnumDisplay((MessageType)item.MessageType)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should be storing the corresponding user readable strings in the database next to the integer. And return an object e.g. `StatusViewModel` to the view model. the View model may have >

```
class StatusViewModel
{

   int type;
   string displayMessage;
}
```

makes sense?

Comment: Yes the downside for me is that it requires yet another table to hold information which is not needed in the database - it's only relevant to the UI